# Flutter intl support of ICU number placeholder "#

Tags: flutter, dart, icu, intl

According to [ICU document](https://phrase.com/blog/posts/guide-to-the-icu-message-format/#DartFlutter),
In a pluralized form message like

```
The film won {n, plural,
one {# award}
other {# awards}}
```

The special # symbol will display the given count in the active locale’s number system.

Currently it seems

```
flutterw pub run intl_utils:generate
```

will not replace # to the given number param.

For example:

```
{number, plural, one {Temporarily inactive (# day left)} other {Temporarily inactive (# days left)}}
```

will generate

```
  String InactiveDaysLeft(num number) {
    return Intl.plural(
      number,
      one: 'Temporarily inactive (# day left)',
      other: 'Temporarily inactive (# days left)',
      name: 'Events_MeetingRoom_InactiveDaysLeft',
      desc: '',
      args: [number],
    );
  }
```

And when using this message, flutter intl does not support this kind of feature either. If a number of 2 is passed to this massage, it will directly return

```
Temporarily inactive (# days left)
```

Does any one know this is by design or its because I did something wrong in practice?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below example. It is somewhat similar to your requirement with dynamic data.

```
String howManyPeople(int numberOfPeople, String place) => Intl.plural(
      numberOfPeople,
      zero: 'I see no one at all in $place.',
      one: 'I see $numberOfPeople other person in $place.',
      other: 'I see $numberOfPeople other people in $place.',
      name: 'howManyPeople',
      args: [numberOfPeople, place],
      desc: 'Description of how many people are seen in a place.',
      examples: const {'numberOfPeople': 3, 'place': 'London'},
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, it clearly shows how to achieve dynamic data by myself. However, the problem here is that there are multiple platforms following the same ICU standard in the company, so the arb files I could receive will always use "#" to represent the first number param. I wonder if there could be a way to achieve this ICU standard using "#" to represent the first number param in dart instead of using regex to force the replacement of all "#" to the first number param by myself LOL

Answer (score 0):

If you are using arb file based localization:

Try

```
"msg": "The film won {n, plural, =1{{n} award} other{{n} awards}}",
@"msg": {
"description": "A generic description",
  "placeholders": {
    "count": {
      "type": "int"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, it clearly shows how to achieve dynamic data by myself. However, the problem here is that there are multiple platforms following the same ICU standard in the company, so the arb files I could receive will always use "#" to represent the first number param. I wonder if there could be a way to achieve this ICU standard using "#" to represent the first number param in dart instead of using regex to force the replacement of all "#" to the first number param by myself LOL

Comment: You can try replacing `n` with `#` to see if it works. I have not tested it though.